# How to pip install *.whl on Windows (using a wildcard)

Tags: python, pip

For some reason, I cannot `pip install %CD%\*.whl` as I will then get:

```
Requirement 'C:\\Users\fredrik\\Downloads\\*.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
`*.whl is not a valid wheel filename.
```

On macOS (and I believe on Linux), I can do this without issues:

```
pip install *.whl
Processing ./certifi-2017.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Processing ./chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Processing ./idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Processing ./requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Processing ./urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl
...
```

---

1. Why is there a difference in this behavior between the platforms?
2. Is there a preferred way to make this (`pip install *.whl`) work on Windows?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/460598/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-windows-cmd-shell-to-expand-wildcard-paths (see the second answer about PowerShell)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you know the package name e.g. `foo`
You can use this:

```
python -m pip install --find-links=C:\Users\fredrik\Downloads foo
```

this will find any `foo` package e.g. `foo-X.Y.Z-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` etc...

If you don't know the package name then you can try:

```
FOR %%i in (C:\Users\fredrik\Downloads\*.whl) DO python -m pip install %i
```

Comment: If you already have a terminal in the desired directory, you can use `pip install --find-links=. foo`